# Switch chart.js data with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am trying to build a dynamic chart using chart.js but I cannot figure out how to swap datasets when clicking buttons.
Some answers here suggest using update() and destroy() with version 2 but they have not worked for me.  I can destroy the data but not then draw the new chart with the correct data set.  Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h67rcsLt/) and code below:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="forecast" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
<button id="0" type="button" >Dataset 1</button>
<button id="1" type="button" >Dataset 2</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var chart_labels = ['06:00', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00'];
var temp_dataset = ['1', '8', '10', '10', '9', '7'];
var rain_dataset = ['0', '0', '6', '32', '7', '2'];

var ctx = document.getElementById("forecast").getContext('2d');

var config = {
    type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: chart_labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        label: "Temperature (Celsius)",
        yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
        fill: false,
        data: temp_dataset,
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: "Precipitation (%)",
        yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
        data: rain_dataset,
      }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        position: "left",
        "id": "y-axis-0",
      }, {
        position: "right",
        "id": "y-axis-1",
      }]
    }
  }
};

var forecast_chart = new Chart(ctx, config);

$("#1").click(function (){
  var chart_labels = ['00:00', '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00'];
  var temp_dataset = ['5', '3', '4', '8', '10', '11', '10', '9'];
  var rain_dataset = ['0', '0', '1', '4', '19', '19', '7', '2'];
  forecast_chart.destroy();
  forecast_chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
});
```

edit* I should add that the initial values should load with the page, the second values on button2 click and the original values on button1 click

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That could be accomplished by replacing the `data` and `labels` array on button click ...

```
$("#0").click(function() {
    var data = forecast_chart.config.data;
    data.datasets[0].data = temp_dataset;
    data.datasets[1].data = rain_dataset;
    data.labels = chart_labels;
    forecast_chart.update();
});

$("#1").click(function() {
    var chart_labels = ['00:00', '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00'];
    var temp_dataset = ['5', '3', '4', '8', '10', '11', '10', '9'];
    var rain_dataset = ['0', '0', '1', '4', '19', '19', '7', '2'];

    var data = forecast_chart.config.data;
    data.datasets[0].data = temp_dataset;
    data.datasets[1].data = rain_dataset;
    data.labels = chart_labels;
    forecast_chart.update();
});
```

Here's the **[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btmzrrcs/)**

Comment: Hi @GRUNT can you help me on similar issue in my thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479353/chartjs-changing-displayed-data-based-on-date ?

Comment: @GRUNT: is it possible to read the data from two different csv files for this scenario , may be using d3.csv function ?